What does object path mean in the dbus-send command?
I have dbus-send command.
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=[service] [objectname] [interface].[method] [parameters]

I've noticed that I can use any object path in the command:
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktor/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames

For example
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus /any_object_path org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames

The reply would be the same.
What does object path mean in the dbus-send command?

It is described in the documentation.

"DBus includes the concept of objects, which are instances of a service that expose one or more interfaces. Objects possess a unique object path used to address them on the bus". What difference in usage. What object path is used for the cllient? If I point out the same object path for different services, does it matter?

It's a similar concept to HTTP URLs (a bit like a REST API). Imagine the destination as HTTP host, and the object path as URL path – the same host (D-Bus service) can let you access various paths (objects).
For example, the UDisks2 service exposes each recognized physical disk as an object:
$ busctl tree org.freedesktop.UDisks2
└─ /org
  └─ /org/freedesktop
    └─ /org/freedesktop/UDisks2
      ├─ /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/Manager
      ├─ /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices
      │ ├─ /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d0
      │ ├─ /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/nvme0n1
      │ ├─ /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/nvme0n1p1
      │ └─ /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/nvme0n1p2
      └─ /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives
        └─ /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/WDC_PC_SN730_SDBQNTY_512G

(See also: busctl introspect, gdbus introspect, D-Spy/D-Feet.)
When you call a function over D-Bus, the service receives a request such as "type: method_call, path: /org…/UDisks2/devices/nvme0n1, method: o.f.DBus.Properties.Get" and handles it in whichever way it likes – it might internally have a mapping of object paths to specific Python objects, for example, or it might parse the path as a string, or do a mix of both. Again similar to HTTP webapps.
Of course, some basic implementations may ignore the path and respond with the same thing to all requests. The special destination "org.freedesktop.DBus" is the bus daemon itself, and it so happens that the original dbus-daemon simply doesn't check the path that was set in the request. (The more modern dbus-broker does check the path, and only the exact path /org/freedesktop/DBus will work.)

What object path is used for the cllient?

Clients don't receive calls (requests), so they don't have object paths.

If I point out the same object path for different services, does it matter?

Each service has its own set of objects, much like each webserver has its own set of URLs; there is no global object namespace.
Some services may provide well-known object paths with identical names across multiple services (such as /org/freedesktop/LogControl1), but those are still distinct objects, as they only "exist" within the respective service processes.
